# Swapping token function in Uniswap V2 failed

Tags: solidity, uniswap, uniswapv2

I am trying to swap multiple tokens to Weth but this transaction gets failed with an error
Fail with error `TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED`

```scss
function swapToWeth(
        address[] calldata tokens,
        uint256[] calldata amounts
    ) public  {
        require(tokens.length == amounts.length, "TokenSwapper: Invalid inputs");
        //to get the total weth converted
        
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            
            if(tokens[i]==address(weth)){
                wethAmount+=amounts[i];
                continue;
            }
            address[] memory path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = tokens[i];
            path[1] = address(weth);

            uint256[] memory amountsOut = uniswapRouter.getAmountsOut(amounts[i], path);
            require(amountsOut[1] > 0, "TokenSwapper: Invalid swap");
            // IERC20(tokens[i]).transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),amounts[i]);
            IERC20(tokens[i]).approve(address(uniswapRouter), amounts[i]);
            uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(
                amounts[i],
                amountsOut[1],
                path,
                address(this),
                block.timestamp
            );
            wethAmount+=amountsOut[0];
            emit make_weth(path[0],path[1],amountsOut);
        }
        emit WethValue(wethAmount);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED` error is happening because the call of `transferFrom` **from** the user, **to** the contract is not happening before the **swap**.

Uniswap Router is trying to extract tokens from your contract, but there are no tokens at this moment on the contract, the tokens are still on the user's account.

Solution:
Add the following line before the `approve` function call to `transferFrom` tokens from **user** to your **smart contract** first:

```
IERC20(tokens[i]).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amounts[i]);
```

The updated code should look like this:

```
IERC20(tokens[i]).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amounts[i]);
IERC20(tokens[i]).approve(address(uniswapRouter), amounts[i]);
```

Now, tokens are first transferred to the smart contract, and then the contract approves the Uniswap Router to use the tokens for the swap. This should resolve the issue.

Additionally, ensure the contract has sufficient allowance from the user before calling `swapToWeth` (better to make this check offchain to save more gas).